# How do you use KeyboardInterrupt without a try statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a basic wage timer for my brother who just got a job... What I wanted to have was a while loop running the code waiting for someone to press enter (or some other key) ends the loop and give the current wage. I was hoping to KeyboardInterrupt but if there is an easier way to do it I would love to hear about it. How could I do this?

Comment: Is there a valid reason you don't want to use a `try-except` statement and catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: You can just wait for keyboard input with a `input()` function call in your script and calculate the elapsed time & wages when it receives one.

Comment: No there is not a reason why I don't want to use try-except. I have never used try-except before thats why I was trying to steer away from it.

Answer (score 0):

a keyboard interrupt is generated only when someone hits ctrl-C or similar.

it sounds like your plan was to have code something like:

```
from time import sleep

wage = 0
try:
    while True:
        wage = wage + hourly_rate
        sleep(60 * 60)  # an hour in seconds
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('you earned', wage)
```

and then have someone hit ctrl-C?  which would work with a try/except.  but if you want someone just to hit the return key then instead of adding things up, do some maths:

```
from time import time

start = time()  # time in seconds from some arbitrary date in 1970 (it's a standard)
input('hit return to get your wage!')
end = time()
elapsed = end - start  # time that has passed in seconds between start and end
wage = hourly_rate * elapsed / (60 * 60)  # convert from hourly
print('you earned', wage)
```

the first version is a bit optimistic as it adds each hour at the start.  the second is more accurate.

ps congrats to your brother!

Comment: Thank you so so so much I am still new to programming... I have been trying to self teach from a book but it is not practical thats why I use stack overflow alot thank you very very much!

Comment: @user2429378 - no problem - if this is what you wanted you can mark the answer as correct (click the tick mark) and i get INTERNET POINTS!

Comment: Niether method works oddly enough... Are you using python 3.3 or higher?

Comment: you have to define `hourly_rate` to whatever he earns.  like `hourly_rate = 30` (30 dollars an hour).  then they work for me in python 3.3.

Comment: Yes I have done that 'code 
from time import time
hourly_rate = 7.50
start = time()
input('hit return to get your wage!')
end = time()
elapsed = end - start  # time that has passed in seconds
wage = hourly_rate * elapsed / (0 * 60)  # convert from hourly
print('you earned', wage)'
Sorry I couldn't get it to do the block code quotes for me.
The error code I am getting is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wage.py", line 15, in <module>
    input('hit return to get your wage!')
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: what editor are you using to write the code?  is this windows?  it looks like maybe you are using something like word in windows and it is putting a "curly quote" at the end of the string (after "wage!").  the quotes should be the same at both ends.  try using notepad and cut+pasting from here?

Comment: I am using A mac. I am using text wrangler, and/or py scripter. I can use my programing computer (pc) inorder to run this